# Configuring font rendering on CentOS - exactly like in WinXP

Tags: centos, fonts, fontconfig

My goal is to configure Courier New font on CentOS7 to look like in Windows XP (XP just for example, not using it). Font configure file at ~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<fontconfig>

<alias>
    <family>monospace</family>
    <prefer><family>Courier New</family></prefer>
  </alias>

<match target="font">
<edit name="antialias" mode="assign">
<bool>false</bool>
</edit>
<edit name="autohint" mode="assign">
<bool>false</bool>
</edit>
<edit name="embeddedbitmap" mode="assign">
<bool>false</bool>
</edit>
<edit name="hinting" mode="assign">
<bool>true</bool>
</edit>
<edit name="hintstyle" mode="assign">
<const>hintslight</const>
</edit>
<edit name="lcdfilter" mode="assign">
<const>lcdlight</const>
</edit>
<edit name="rgba" mode="assign">
<const>rgb</const>
</edit>
</match>

</fontconfig>
```

Courier New fonts installed.

**Bad** result on CentOS:

[image]

**Good** result on Win10:

[image]

Tried with option:

```
<edit name="antialias" mode="assign">
<bool>true</bool>
</edit>
```

Even **worse**:

[image]

**EDIT:**

With `ftview` (thanks to @contemplator for good hint) I found the exact match, the problem now is how to convert those settings to xml:

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

It seems like FreeType is involved by setting:

```
export FREETYPE_PROPERTIES="truetype:interpreter-version=35"
```

Here is more related info:
[image]

Now trying to find how set the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @contemplator for pointing to `ftview`, I found the solution:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<fontconfig>

  <alias>
    <family>monospace</family>
    <prefer><family>Courier New</family></prefer>
  </alias>

  <match target="font">
      <edit name="antialias" mode="assign">
          <bool>false</bool>
      </edit>
      <edit name="hinting" mode="assign">
          <bool>true</bool>
      </edit>
      <edit name="autohint" mode="assign">
          <bool>false</bool>
      </edit>
      <edit name="hintstyle" mode="assign">
          <const>hintfull</const>
      </edit>
  </match>

</fontconfig>
```

Then create the file at `/etc/profile.d/freetype2.sh`:

```
# Subpixel hinting mode can be chosen by setting the right TrueType interpreter
# version. The available settings are:
#
#     truetype:interpreter-version=35  # Classic mode (default in 2.6)
#     truetype:interpreter-version=38  # Infinality mode
#     truetype:interpreter-version=40  # Minimal mode (default in 2.7)
#
# There are more properties that can be set, separated by whitespace. Please
# refer to the FreeType documentation for details.

# Uncomment and configure below
export FREETYPE_PROPERTIES="truetype:interpreter-version=35"
```

After re-login, bingo :) The text is now superb, clean and easy to read (using Eizo ColorEdge CG243W high-end graphic monitor):

[image]

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```xml
 <match target="font">
   <test name="family" qual="any">
     <string>Courier New</string>
   </test>
   <edit name="antialias" mode="assign">
     <bool>false</bool>
   </edit>
   <edit name="hinting" mode="assign">
     <bool>true</bool>
   </edit>
   <edit name="hintstyle" mode="assign">
     <const>hintfull</const>
   </edit>
 </match>
```

This is how it looks, seems identical to me: [image: ftview.png]

Comment: Didn't helped - the same..

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis, I've updated the code, try again please.

Comment: The same.. Perhaps it's related to Courier New fonts - they are different from Windows OS?

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis, if you installed the font with msttcorefonts package it is probably not the latest version. I've imported the font directly from a Win10 installation, see the screenshot how it renders here.

Comment: Yes, looks identical. And I listed my fonts - there are strange versions of Courier New.. Could you describe how to import those fonts?

Comment: Copy font files to `~/.fonts/`, delete the old one.

Comment: I have placed at `/usr/share/fonts/winxp/cour.ttf`, then `fc-cache`, opened `gedit`, and still those strange "A" letters like in my screenshots above..

Comment: And "h" letters..

Comment: Check for yourself how it looks with ftview, like this: `ftview -r 96 11 cour.ttf`, see built-in help for how to switch rendering options.

Comment: After a lot of playing found exact match: `monochrome`, `hinting: on`, `forced-auto: off`, `engine: v35`, `bitmaps: on` (makes no difference), `color bitmaps: off` (makes no difference), `cache: off` (makes no difference), `gamma: sRGB mode`  (makes no difference). Now - how to convert to xml :) `monochrome`, `engine: v35`, `bitmaps: on`?